# How to choose a random time once per hour

Tags: random, time

Suppose I want to run a task once per hour, but at a variable time during the hour. It doesn't have to be truly random; I just don't want to do it at the top of the hour every hour, for example.  And I want to do it once per hour only.

This eliminates several obvious approaches, such as sleeping a random amount of time between 30 and 90 minutes, then sleeping again. It would be possible (and pretty likely) for the task to run several times in a row with a sleep of little more than 30 minutes.

The approach I'm thinking about looks like this: every hour, hash the Unix timestamp of the hour, and mod the result by 3600. Add the result to the Unix timestamp of the hour, and that's the moment when the task should run. In pseudocode:

```
while now = clock.tick; do
  // now = a unix timestamp
  hour = now - now % 3600;
  hash = md5sum(hour);
  the_time = hour + hash % 3600;
  if now == the_time; then
    do_the_work();
  end
end
```

I'm sure this will meet my requirements, but I thought it would be fun to throw this question out and see what ideas other people have!

Comment: But tomorrow at 9:00am is not the same Unix timestamp as today at 9:00am, so there will be a different input. I neglected to say I was using Unix timestamp. Will update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly. If the total duration is e.g. 10 hours, you want the task to run exactly ten times?

Comment: Good question. I see I didn't really state an assumption. This is a long-running (runs forever?) program that loops once a second. It does a bunch of work every second. Once an hour, but at a variable time, I want it to do another little task.

Comment: It just occurred to me that instead of using a hash function, I could use the hour's timestamp as the seed to rand(). The result is still predictable, but may have better distribution, depending on the hash function.

Answer (score 1):

For the next hour to do work in, just pick a random minute within that hour.

That is, pick a random time for the *next* interval to do work in; this might be the same interval (hour) as the current interval (hour) if work has carried over from the previous interval.

The "time to sleep" is simply the time until then. This could also be execute "immediately" on a carry-over situation if the random time was before now: this will ensure that a random time is picked *each* hour, unless work takes more than an hour.

Don't make it more complex than it has to be - there is no reason to hash or otherwise muck with `random` here. This is how "Enterprise" solutions like SharePoint Timers (with an Hourly Schedule) work.

Comment: I would agree but for the fact that this allows the task to re-run in failure cases. For example, if the process is restarted and loses the choice it made. The choice can be made reasonably durable with readily available technology, but that's complex and isn't absolutely guaranteed to be durable (ask me how I know!)

I actually don't think my idea is more complex than yours, although please don't take that as criticism of your idea. The whole point of this post was to stimulate creative ideas :)

Comment: On the other hand, if wanted an unpredictable choice of time, your idea is clearly better. My idea picks a variable, but completely predictable, time.

Comment: @BaronSchwartz I'm just going off what I know for timer/job spacing. For handling error-recovery situations an "ACID" store works quite well, although such constraints might be able to be relaxed to something as simple as a sentinel file or controlling container. I'm not entirely sure why a predictable, but non-constant, time derived from a formula would be beneficial over "20 minutes past the hour" (which is itself one valid way to specify the next time).

Comment: I want to sample some data, but I don't always want to do it at the same time, so as to avoid getting a skewed view. For example, if there is a routine task running at 20 minutes past the hour, and that's when I always sample my data, I'll end up believing that task runs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Schedule your task (with cron or the like) to run at the top of every hour.
2. At the beginning of your task, sleep for a random amount of time, from 0 to (60 - (*the estimated running time of your task* + *a fudge factor*)) minutes.
3. If you don't want your task to run twice simultaneously, you can use a pid file. The task can check - after sleeping - for this file and wait for the currently running task to finish before starting again.

Comment: I have the same comments about this idea as about pst's idea; there is some complexity inherent in handling error cases. Good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed my suggested solution and it is working very well. For example, once per minute I sample some information from a process I'm monitoring, but I do it at variable times during the minute. I created a method of a Timestamp type, called RandomlyWithin, as follows, in Go code:

```
func (t Timestamp) RandomlyWithin(dur Timestamp, entropy ...uint32) Timestamp {
    intervalStart := t - t % dur
    toHash := uint32(intervalStart)
    if len(entropy) > 0 {
        toHash += entropy[0]
    }
    md5hasher.Reset()
    md5hasher.Write([]byte{
        uint8(toHash >> 24 & 255),
        uint8(toHash >> 16 & 255),
        uint8(toHash >> 8 & 255),
        uint8(toHash & 255)})
    randomNum := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(md5hasher.Sum(nil)[0:4])
    result := intervalStart + Timestamp(randomNum)%dur
    return result
}
```